# reading and writing sd card txt csv file arduino at 62.5kHz

Tags: file, arduino

I am having an issue with writing on a SD card when the frequency is 62.5 kHz.

> TCCR0B = (TCCR0B & 0b11111000) | 0x01 - is what i used

I tried the original setting and it works but not when i changed it.

> TCCR0B = (TCCR0B & 0b11111000) | 0x03 - original setting

Is there anything i can do to read/write on SD card when using 62.5 kHz? Reason why i need 62.5 kHz is for the PWM signal at pin 5 and 6.

Comment: My guess - The Arduino SD card library uses `millis()` or `micros()` or `delay()` and you've just changed it to run 64 times faster.

Comment: @KIIV i open both SD.cpp and SD.h but failed to see `millis()`, `micros()` and `delay()`. Or did i misunderstand your meaning? how can i change it to run 64 times faster? inserting `TCCR0B = (TCCR0B & 0b11111000) | 0x01` in SD.cpp?

Comment: Timer/Counter 0 is used for counting milliseconds since start on most Arduinos. This value is also used for all delays (at least for those in the Arduino core). So if you change prescaler from 64 to 1, you've just changed 1.024ms interrupt period (yes, millis are not so precise) to 16us.

Comment: Running it 64 times faster or changing it to 16us is a no no when using SD card library? too fast the arduino got furious? Is there a limit?

Comment: Not too fast for arduino, but flash devices needs some time to write data. If you are waiting 1/64th of required time (Page Write time), it won't work properly.

Comment: Eventually SPI is speed affected by this timer? Sure you're using the Hardware-SPI for your SD card?